# How to fix DB2 sqlcode=-805 in a REXX mainframe script with execsql prepare

Tags: db2, mainframe, rexx

When I run the REXX script :

```
/* REXX */                                               
CALL CONNIN /* CONNECTION */                             
ADDRESS DSNREXX "EXECSQL DECLARE C1 CURSOR FOR S1"       
IF SQLCODE \= 0 THEN DO                                  
   ERRMSG = "EXECSQL DECLARE"                             
   CALL SQLCA                                             
END                                                      
TTABLE = "ibmuser.dept"                        
SQLSMT = "SELECT * FROM :TTABLE"                         
ADDRESS DSNREXX "EXECSQL PREPARE S1 FROM :SQLSMT"        
IF SQLCODE \= 0 THEN DO                                  
   ERRMSG = "EXECSQL PREPARE"                             
   CALL SQLCA                                             
END                                                      
CALL CLOSING /*CLOSING ALL*/                             
EXIT 0                                                   
/*ROUTINES CALLED*/                                      
/*INITIAL CONNECTION*/                                   
CONNIN:
SSID = "DBCG"                                            
ADDRESS TSO "SUBCOM DSNREXX"                             
IF RC THEN S_RC = RXSUBCOM("ADD","DSNREXX","DSNREXX")    
ADDRESS DSNREXX "CONNECT" SSID                           
IF SQLCODE \= 0 THEN DO                                  
   ERRMSG = "CONNECT TO" SSID "FAILED."                   
   CALL SQLCA                                             
END                                                      
RETURN                                                   
/* ERROR HANDLING ROUTINE */                             
SQLCA:                                                   
SAY " ERROR MSG=  >"ERRMSG"<"                            
SAY " SQLCODE  =  >"SQLCODE"<"                           
SAY " SQLSTATE =  >"SQLSTATE"<"                          
SAY " SQLERRMC =  >"SQLERRMC"<"                          
SAY " SQLERRP  =  >"SQLERRP"<"                           
SAY " SQLERRD.1=  >"SQLERRD.1"<"                         
SAY " SQLERRD.2=  >"SQLERRD.2"<"                         
SAY " SQLERRD.3=  >"SQLERRD.3"<"
SAY " SQLERRD.4=  >"SQLERRD.4"<"                 
SAY " SQLERRD.5=  >"SQLERRD.5"<"                 
SAY " SQLERRD.6=  >"SQLERRD.6"<"                 
EXIT 8                                           
RETURN                                           
/* CLOSING */                                    
CLOSING:
ADDRESS DSNREXX "DISCONNECT"                     
S_RC = RXSUBCOM("DELETE","DSNREXX","DSNREXX") 
RETURN
```

After running I receive the error messages :

```
ERROR MSG=  >EXECSQL PREPARE<                             
SQLCODE  =  >-805<                                        
SQLSTATE =  >51002<                                       
SQLERRMC =  >DALLASC..DSNREXX.1AB2405808DB7F29:DSNREXX:03<
SQLERRP  =  >DSNXEPM <                                    
SQLERRD.1=  >-251<                                        
SQLERRD.2=  >0<                                           
SQLERRD.3=  >0<                                           
SQLERRD.4=  >-1<                                          
SQLERRD.5=  >0<                                           
SQLERRD.6=  >0<
```

The error comes from : ADDRESS DSNREXX "EXECSQL PREPARE S1 FROM :SQLSMT"
With SPUFI (db2 utility) I can list the table IBMUSER.DEPT with select * from ibmuser.dept;
How I can fix this issue?
Thanks

Comment: -805 always means the plan is not correctly bound or the contained packages are the wrong version (e.g. not up to date). Since in your case this is about the DSNREXX-package which should be maintained by your systems-guys you should contact them and ask them to correct the issue,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @piet.t and @bruce-martin for the suggestions. The issue was because the DSNREXX was not enabled for public usage.

Answer (score 3):

I would try

```
TTABLE = "ibmuser.dept"                        
SQLSMT = "SELECT * FROM" TTABLE
```

Error [-805](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPEK_10.0.0/codes/src/tpc/n805.html) is

```
-805   DBRM OR PACKAGE NAME location-name.collection-id.dbrm-name.consistency-token NOT FOUND IN PLAN plan-name. REASON
```

The full message will tell you what DB2 can not find. If you can not find it, try looking in your TSO job output

Comment: I tried your suggestion but still the same error. According with the SQLSTATE table list, with sqlstate=51002, the error is "The package corresponding to an SQL statement execution request was not found. -805". For me the error explained have nothing to do with the table name, more with the PREPARE action and his package version, what do you think?

Comment: You may not have access to the default package or it might not be setup. Find out what the package name is and talk to the DBA's